# Change display html table in view on Yii Framework

Tags: php, view, yii, html-table

I have made a module for financial management using Yii php framework and installed the model, controller, CRUD , and views through Gii. Now I want to display the contents created for each financial movement in a table , one movement per row, inside the view movements page - such as in the admin.php (the manage control), but without the ability to update them.

I'm very new to Yii and, even though I tried very hard, Yii seems to be too obscure for me to achieve anything. How can I make my movement/views/view.php display a HTML table with the all the entries from my movement table?

--UPDATE:

Here is the code form _view.php

```
    <?php

/* @var $this MovementController */
/* @var $data Financialmovement */

$due = gmdate( 'd/m/Y', $data->due_date );

if ( $data->pay_date != 0 ) {
    $pay = gmdate( 'd/m/Y', $data->pay_date );
} else {
    $pay = 'Indisponível';
}
switch ( $data->category ):
    case ('trn'):
        $category = "Transporte";
        break;
    case ('fin'):
        $category = "Financeiro";
        break;
    default :
        $category = 'Erro! Valor nulo.';
endswitch;

if ( $data->condition = 1 ) {
    $condition = 'Concluída';
} else {
    $condition = 'Aberta';
}

if ( $data->movement_type = 1 ) {
    $type = 'Saída';
} else {
    $type = 'Entrada';
}


$value = $data->value;
$patern = '/\./';
$replacement = ',';
$value = preg_replace( $patern, $replacement, $value );

$coin = $data->coin_type;
$patern = '/s/';
$replacement = '$';
$coin = preg_replace( $patern, $replacement, $coin );

?>

<tr class="wide form">
    <td >
        <?php echo $data->getAttributeLabel( 'id' ); ?>:
        <?php echo CHtml::link( ( $data->id ), array( 'view', 'id' => $data->id ) ); ?>

    </td>
    <td >
        <?php echo $data->getAttributeLabel( 'category' ); ?>:
        <?php echo $category; ?>

    </td>
    <td >
        <?php echo $data->getAttributeLabel( 'value' ); ?>:
        <?php echo '<span class="capital">' . $coin . "</span> " . $value; ?>

    </td>
    <td >
        <?php echo $data->getAttributeLabel( 'due_date' ); ?>:
        <?php echo $due; ?>

    </td>
    <td >
        <?php echo $data->getAttributeLabel( 'pay_date' ); ?>:
        <?php echo $pay; ?>

    </td>
    <td >
        <?php echo $data->getAttributeLabel( 'description' ); ?>:
        <?php echo $data->description; ?>

    </td>
    <td >
        <?php echo $data->getAttributeLabel( 'condition' ); ?>:
        <?php echo $condition; ?>

    </td>
    <td >
        <?php echo $data->getAttributeLabel( 'movement_type' ); ?>:
        <?php echo $type; ?>

    </td>
    <td >
        <?php echo $data->getAttributeLabel( 'observation' ); ?>:
        <?php echo $data->observation; ?>

    </td>
</tr>
```

Here is the code for view.php:

```
    <?php

/* @var $this MovementController */
/* @var $model Financialmovement */

$this->breadcrumbs = array(
    'Financial Movements' => array( 'index' ),
    $model->id,
);

$this->menu = array(
    array( 'label' => 'List Financial Movement', 'url' => array( 'index' ) ),
    array( 'label' => 'Create Financial Movement', 'url' => array( 'create' ) ),
    array( 'label' => 'Update Financial Movement', 'url' => array( 'update', 'id' => $model->id ) ),
    array( 'label' => 'Delete Financial Movement', 'url' => '#', 'linkOptions' => array( 'submit' => array( 'delete', 'id' => $model->id ), 'confirm' => 'Are you sure you want to delete this item?' ) ),
    array( 'label' => 'Manage Financial Movement', 'url' => array( 'admin' ) ),
);

?>

<h1>View Financial Movement #<?php echo $model->id; ?></h1>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Id</td>
    </tr>
    <?php

    $dataProvider = new CActiveDataProvider( 'Financialmovement' );

    $this->widget( 'zii.widgets.CListView', array(
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'itemView' => '_view', // refers to the partial view named '_view'
        'sortableAttributes' => array(
            'id',
            'due_date',
            'pay_date',
            'category',
        ),
    ) );

    ?>
</table>
```

Comment: echo the data and check in what format it is available on view page and set the html view according to that

Comment: w00t do not put logic in your view, that's ugly

Answer (score 1):

At first you should get table data in controller via CActiveDataProvider. And then in view you can use widget - CGridView. Using this widget you can set params that you need. Columns, filters etc. Also you can paste your code, and we will try to decide your problem.
Yii is very easy :)

Comment: But should I put it in the _view file or the view file it self? I did use CGridView in view.php , but It made no effect. What do I put in _view.php and what do I put in view.php?

Comment: I've updated the question to withhold the codes , hope It helps you to help me.

Comment: As i can see, you need show calculating data in table, right? But CGridView not support _view.php template for each row. You have two ways to decide this problem. 1. CGridView have columns settings:
    'columns'=>array(
        array(
            'name'=>'id',
            'value' => '$data->id'
        )
     ).
In this case you can customize the output columns of the table as you need. The 2nd way: use CListView and build table manually.

Comment: Do I need to change _view as well? I added :
`$this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    'itemView'=>'_view',   // refers to the partial view named '_view'
    'sortableAttributes'=>array(
        'due_date',
        'pay_date',
    ),
));`

Comment: Before widget you need add table header: <table><tr><th>...</th>...</tr>. Then define widget and change _view.php according to to table html(change div to TR and TD). And after widget - close table: </table>

Comment: Please put error message and defining dataProvider in controller. Seems in View all ok

Comment: Sorry , man , really am , I was editing the wrong file all along, it was supposed to be index.php for the module. So sorry, I'll ask the staff to remove this question, again sooooo sorry.